# How can I guarantee before_destroy callback order in autosave records?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback

I'm implementing an audit-trail-esque system in my rails3 app; basically, I want to keep track of exactly when my users make any changes.

Currently facing an issue where I have two models - one child to the other.  Pseudocode follows:

```
class Audit;end #this is a straightforward data-storing model, trust me!  
class Parent
  has_many :children, :dependent => :destroy
  before_destroy :audit_destroy
  def audit_destroy
     Audit.create(:metadata => "some identifying data")
  end
end
class Child
  belongs_to :parent
  before_destroy :audit_destroy
  def audit_destroy
     Audit.create(:metadata => "some identifying data")
  end
end
```

On calling

```
Parent.destroy
```

I'm expecting two new Audit records to be created with created_at timestamps that are ordered relative to the parent records.  Said slightly differently:  the parent record's Audit is created before the child record's Audit.

This doesn't, however, seem to be guaranteed, as I haven't explicitly said anything about the order of creation of the audit records.  While it seems to usually hold true, I have confirmed that sometimes the order of the creation of the Audit records is inverted.

Is there some magic in the depths of ActiveRecord surrounding the ordering of before_destroy callbacks creating new records and autosave?

Thanks,
Isaac